# Extract minimum set of files needed for a website

Tags: html, extract, required

I have a web site that currently has a lot of unused CSS files, javascript files, etc. I want to re-factor it but I need to determine what is actually used. I would like a simple way to extract as many the necessary files as possible and leave the cruft behind. There are web scrapers out there but they either cost money or don't do quite what I want. Any useful suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do what you want?

http://unused-css.com/

If you are unwilling to pay I think you are going to run into some trouble here I think.

Here's a firefox addon that claims to do this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/